# Weblogic security realm - user from java code

Tags: java, security, weblogic

I have simple application deployed on weblogic (12) server. On Security realms I've created user with password. Now I want to use those credentials to connect from the java client code (inside my app) to some external server (like LDAP). Is this possible? To use user defined in realms without passing password (cause password will be defined on weblogic)?
What is the best practice for storing user credentials (for connecting to other systems)?

Comment: What have you tried? It's hard to figure out what exactly you want to do... the basics of creating a weblogic context can be found here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/jndi/jndi.html

Comment: I had only add user with password into weblogic security realm. My question is it possible to use this user credential inside java application - not for web site authorization but for log into other external server?

Comment: I think the answer to that is no, an external server will have no knowledge of the internal weblogic user. If the user was in LDAP that both servers use, it would work but not if it is a "weblogic only" user.